# What is decalage and how it affects airplane performance?

Tags: wing, airfoil, stability

What is decalage in airplanes and how important is it in respect to  airplane performance?

Answer (score 5):

[This article from flying magazine](https://www.flyingmag.com/pilots-places/pilots-adventures-more/truth-about-wing-incidence) has a nice definition (including some history)

> Decalage — a French word meaning “shift” or “offset” — is, broadly
>   speaking, a difference between the incidences of any two lifting
>   surfaces. It was originally applied to the two wings of a biplane: In
>   the usual arrangement, the upper wing was farther forward than the
>   lower and had a larger (can’t get away from that term!) angle of
>   incidence — called positive decalage — so that it stalled first,
>   shifting the center of lift aft and providing an automatic nose-down
>   moment for recovery.
>
> In a monoplane, the term refers to the angles at which the wing and
>   the stabilizer (or canard) are attached to the fuselage. For an
>   airplane to be longitudinally stable, it must have positive
>   aerodynamic decalage; roughly speaking, the forward surface must be at
>   a greater angle of attack than the aft one. This principle applies to
>   conventional airplanes and to canards alike.